# Update Meteor package ahead of release

Tags: git, github, meteor, meteorite

There is a Meteor package (`edgee:slingshot`) that has new features in its master branch, but not yet in a release (so it can't be updated with `meteor update`).

How does one update a package from a GitHub repo, in a clean way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a `packages` directory in the root of your project if there isn't already one there.
Clone the repo into the packages directory. At this point it's probably worth changing the version number in the `package.js`, just to be sure you're adding that package and not the version from the repository.
Now when you `meteor add my:package` (or whatever), you should see it add your new version number, indicating that your local version has been installed.

**NB** - if you're doing a lot of this sort of thing (i.e. it's more than a one-off, temporary fix), it's advisable to put local packages in a separate directory and symlink to them.  I did a quick talk about this at the last London Devshop, which should be online soon.

Comment: Comprehensive answer! And if you are building and testing a local package, this is how you'd do it also.

Comment: also using METEOR_PACKAGES env variable can help not managing symlinks